# How to check if a cell is invalid, and set a default value if it's invalid?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell that has a named range for its list validation.  What I want to do is this: check if the current contents of the cell violate its validation, and if so, set the cell to the first value in the named range list.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub defaultIfInvalid(rng As Range)

Dim formula As String
formula = rng.Validation.Formula1
formula = Mid(formula, 2)  'remove the equal sign on the front
If Range(formula).Find(rng.value) Is Nothing Then
    rng.value = Range(formula)(1).value
End If


End Sub
```

But this line:

```
If Range(formula).Find(rng.value) Is Nothing
```

gives the following error:

```
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

How can I perform this check/setting to default?

EDIT: If it's helpful, the validation is a dynamic formula that selects from several different named ranges based on the contents of one of the cells.  Formatted here for clarity:

```
=IF('On-Call Search Form'!$C$6="On-Call Contact",OnCallGroup,
IF(OR('On-Call Search Form'!$C$6="district",
      'On-Call Search Form'!$C$6="division"),
   RegionalGroup,FunctionGroup))
```

`OnCallGroup`, `RegionalGroup`, and `FunctionGroup` are all static ranges, e.g., `OnCallGroup` is:

```
=Selections!$S$2:$S$7
```

Comment: If you don't need a macro you can do this with a simple formula, `IFERROR`

Comment: @Sam, there won't be an error in the cell; the validation is set dynamically based on changes to the contents of other cells on the same sheet, e.g. `IF(A1="hello",namedRange1,namedRange2)`.

Comment: what is the formula of your data validation? and also what type of data validation do you use?

Comment: What is the value of formula when you get to that line?

Comment: @simoco, I've added details to the question with the validation formula.  This is a list validation.

Comment: @Zaider, see added details above.

Comment: `rng.Validation.Formula1` returns formula itself but not result of formula, and `Range(formula).` evaluates to `Range("IF(...)").`

Comment: @simoco, how can I get the range that the formula evaluates to? e.g., how can i return `$S$2:$S$7`?

Comment: try `Set rngNew=Evaluate(formula)` for returning range (untested)

Comment: @simoco, That works, I'll accept that if you post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
Dim formula As String
Dim rngNew As Range

formula = rng.Validation.Formula1
Set rngNew=Evaluate(formula)
If rngNew.Find(rng.value) Is Nothing Then
    'do something
End If
```